# TextView autoSizeTextType not working in app widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Can't get TextView text autosize to work in an app widget.

The autosize shows fine in Android Studio's preview, but it doesn't work on the actual widget.

Is autosize not supposed to work in widgets or something?

My TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/widget_text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="#ddd"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" 
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="200dp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12dp"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is autosize not supposed to work in widgets or something?

Your layout assumes that it is being inflated by something that understands those `app`-prefixed attributes. In the case of an [app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview), that will not be the case. The system inflates the layout using a stock `LayoutInflater`, and it knows nothing about those attributes. The reason those attributes work in an `AppCompatActivity` is because it substitutes its own `LayoutInflater` which honors those `app`-prefixed attributes.

You are welcome to use `android` for those (e.g., `android:autoSizeTextType`). However, they will only be honored on Android 8.0 and higher, when auto-sizing was added to the framework.

If auto-sizing is critical for the operation of your app widget, you will need to set your `minSdkVersion` to 26.

Comment: Thanks. Lost count of the hours I wasted on this, at least now I know why. Min sdk 26 is obvs not an option. Also, I've seen apps supporting even older sdks doing the text autosize in widgets just fine. Guess I'll have to find a way to update the text size manually based on the current widget size.

Comment: @pt2ph8: The algorithms that are used for calculating this stuff are kinda nasty (see the 822-line `AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper` in the `androidx.appcompat` sources). However, you may be able to work out a simpler algorithm that handles a restricted set of conditions.

Comment: I'm experimenting with loading the layout programmatically, setting the values then converting the views into bitmaps, and setting them to ImageViews in the widget's layout. The ImageView sizes are updated along with the widget's size and it seems to work well so far.

Comment: @pt2ph8: Be careful when putting bitmaps on a `RemoteViews` that you won't [run into a `TransactionTooLargeException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619566/android-transactiontoolargeexception-with-notificationmanager#comment99812333_56619566). Consider using a `ContentProvider` to serve those images.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Widgets, the `android:autoSizeTextType` will work but the support will be from Android 8.0 only.

As app widgets are rendered by the home screen and the home screen might not know about the `app` namespace.

Comment: You cannot assume that the home screen is using any particular library, and it is the home screen that is rendering an app widget. And you cannot set it dynamically in an app widget, as you do not have the `View`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Its about Android support libraries which his app widget is using not home screen.

Comment: The title of the question is "TextView autoSizeTextType not working in app widget". The first sentence of the question is "Can't get TextView text autosize to work in an app widget.". We have to assume that the question refers to [app widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview).

Comment: It's working with "android:". But I get a warning saying the attribute is used in API 26 and my min is 21. Any thought?

Comment: @CommonsWare You mean to say app widgets are not application? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets

Comment: I am saying that app widgets are not rendered by the app. They are *defined* by the app, but they are rendered by the home screen and the system. They have the actual `View` objects -- the app only has the layout and `RemoteViews`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Got it!. I was on a totally different page.  Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited the answer now. Thanks again for all the info.

Comment: Your first paragraph is fine. The second paragraph works for activities and fragments, but not for app widgets.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited the answer again. Feel free to edit or delete .